# Program returns a blank page

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I wrote a program to be able to register with an accont or login. For some reason, when I run the program I get a blank page with nothing on it. I'm expecting to have a menu page where I can either click on "Login" which will get me to the login page, or "Register" which doesn't do anything yet. Here is my full code:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')
Menu = Frame(root)
loginPage = Frame(root)
registerPage = Frame(root)
def show_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
show_frame(Menu)
# Menu Page
Menu.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

TitleF1 = Label(Menu, text="Menu", font=("Arial", 25), bg="#B3C7D6")
TitleF1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=25)

MenuButton1 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Login", command=lambda: show_frame(loginPage))
MenuButton1.grid(row=1, column=0)

MenuButton2 = Button(Menu, width=25, text="Register", command=lambda: show_frame(registerPage))
MenuButton2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)


# Login Page

loginUsernameL = Label(loginPage, text='Username').place(x=30, y=60)
loginUsernameE = Entry(loginPage).place(x=120, y=60)
loginPasswordL = Label(loginPage, text='Password').place(x=30, y=90)
loginPasswordE = Entry(loginPage).place(x=120, y=90)
backButton = Button(loginPage, text='Back').place(x=0, y=0)
loginButton = Button(loginPage, text='Login', width=20).place(x=70, y=150)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You never added your menu to the root display. Put this somewhere under your `# Menu Page` comment `Menu.grid(sticky='nswe')`

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('300x200')


def menu():
    def login():
        TitleF1.destroy()
        MenuButton1.destroy()
        MenuButton2.destroy()
        def back():
            loginUsernameL.destroy()
            loginUsernameE.destroy()
            loginPasswordL.destroy()
            loginPasswordE.destroy()
            backButton.destroy()
            loginButton.destroy()
            menu()
        loginUsernameL = Label(root, text='Username')
        loginUsernameL.place(x=30, y=60)
        loginUsernameE = Entry(root)
        loginUsernameE.place(x=120, y=60)
        loginPasswordL = Label(root, text='Password')
        loginPasswordL.place(x=30, y=90)
        loginPasswordE = Entry(root)
        loginPasswordE.place(x=120, y=90)
        backButton = Button(root, text='Back', command=back)
        backButton.place(x=0, y=0)
        loginButton = Button(root, text='Login', width=20)
        loginButton.place(x=70, y=150)
        
    TitleF1 = Label(root, text="Menu", font=("Arial", 25), bg="#B3C7D6")
    TitleF1.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=25, padx=110)
    MenuButton1 = Button(root, width=25, text="Login", command=login)
    MenuButton1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    MenuButton2 = Button(root, width=25, text="Register")
    MenuButton2.grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10)

menu()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: your answer doesn't explain why OP's code doesn't work. it would be great if you could explain your code and why it works. this can be done with comments inside the code or as free text. as it is it might work just fine but is not actually all that helpful.